# JPA/Hibernate Row Lock

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, locking

Within a transaction of a Stateless Bean method I have following code:

```
Account accountOne = entityManager.find(Account.class, 1L); 
accountOne.setAccountBalance(100L);

List<Account> allAcounts = entityManager.createQuery("select obj from Account 
obj").getResultList();
```

As I have discovered, triggers the last instruction *getResultList* indirectly the flush() method of the *EntityManager*. This causes by the way a database row lock of the database row which belongs to the entity *accountOne*.

Is there a way to get the information when hibernate is locking a row (a kind of listener or anything else)?